# How to keep CSS persistent in WebView

Tags: javascript, android, css, webview

This is the code I am trying to follow; the onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  I am using to inject my own css into an external site. Unfortunately with Webview it renders the page first and then applies the CSS. How can I go about waiting for the page to render and then the javascript applied before having it displayed?

Is there an easier method with WebClient HTTP Get and redirect the CSS to one locally?

Thank you for your suggestions in advance!

```
com.webkitdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebKitDemo extends Activity
{
final Activity activity = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

//addition final webview

final WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_engine);  
/* JavaScript must be enabled if you want it to work, obviously */  
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  




webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
{
activity.setTitle(" Loading...");
activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

if(progress == 100)
activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
}
});

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String                       failingUrl)
{
// Handle the error
}

//additions

@Override 
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
{  
  webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  
      "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color = 'green'; " +  
      "})()"); 
}  
//

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
{
webView.loadUrl(url);
return true;
}



});
webView.loadUrl("http://code.google.com");
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this before your style changing code. That way it'll only be executed when the page is finished loading.

```
var oldonload = window.onload;
if (typeof window.onload != 'function')
    {
    window.onload = yourfunctionhere();
    } 
else 
    {
    window.onload = function()
    {
    yourfunctionhere();
    oldonload();
    }
}
```